# Google Tag Manager writes weird code snippet

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have been including the google tag management code since some time now on my homepage, but since one day(or so) there seems to be an issue. At the bottom of the body it includes some minified facebook script which seems to cause an error since it adds `fbq('track', 'ViewContent'); fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '35.00', currency: 'EUR'});` to the DOM of the page.

I put a code like this right after the body tag:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: That `fbq` looks like [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/tag-api) code.

Comment: It looks, like you have a [FB pixel installed at your GTM](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1021909254506499).

Comment: Oh I see, since I don't administrate the GTM for that page it seems to be added to GTM, thanks for making it clear!